# Two threads calling an increment method synchronized on "this" elasped time lower than expected

Tags: java, multithreading

Count is: 20000 Time elapsed: 5001

I get this result when I type the following code, I have a class that has a count variable that is incremented in a synchronized block on "this", why when I make a new object of Exercise in main and then 2 threads with 2 anon runnable's calling ex.increment does it time only 5 seconds? shouldn't it be 10 seconds total because one thread acquires a lock and does it's work while the other should wait? I get the idea of synchronized but I am just confused why if I was to make Exercise implement runnable and pass it into the Thread() constructors it would take 10 seconds, but not this way, please explain thanks.

```
public class Exercise {
    private int count = 0;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void increment() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercise ex = new Exercise();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ex.increment();
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ex.increment();
            }
        });

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Count is: " + ex.getCount() + " Time elapsed: " + (end - start));
    }
}
```

Comment: _When_ is the lock acquired? Before or after `sleep`? In other words, do the `sleep` calls execute concurrently or one after the other?

Comment: Wait so what you're saying is the methods sleep simultaneously for 5 seconds while the synchronized blocks actually execute serially to each other outside those 5 seconds?

Comment: What reason would they have for waiting for eachother?

Comment: When i read your comment, I put the sleep in the synchronized block and got 10 seconds, I think I comprehend it now, I tried AtomicInteger after without a sync block and got 5 seconds, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both threads sleep in almost parallel for 5 seconds.

Then some thread gets into the synced block and runs the loop in an instant. Then the other thread does the same.

There is nothing surprising here.